# Accessing function in MasterViewController from DetailViewController (swift)

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a function in MasterViewController

```
 func removeLocation(city: String){
        objects.removeObject(city)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
```

In my DetailViewController I check whether the city is valid and if its not, I want to remove it from the table in MasterViewController. I pass self in prepareForSegue() from MasterView to DetailView and I assign it to

```
 var masterViewController: MasterViewController
```

But then I get an error saying that it is not initialized and it want me to have this initializer

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Which breaks my whole program when I run it and gives me an expected fatal error.

Ho I can create an instance of MasterView in DetailView without an initializer, or access a function in MasterView from DetailView?

This is Swift btw, I found some advices on how to solve it in C but I couldn't implement them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an optional.

```
var masterViewController: MasterViewController?
```

Optionals do not have to be initialized when the class is created.

In `prepareForSegue()` assign the pointer as usual:

```
destinationViewController.masterViewController = self
```

Then when you need to call `removeLocation`:

```
masterViewController?.removeLocation("London")
```

Comment: Thank you! But now I still have to go back to MasterView from DetailView and only then the city is removed. Is there a way to automatically redirect to MasterView after the entry was deleted from the table in MasterView?

Comment: I'm not following you.  Could you describe how you want this would work from the user's perspective?

Comment: Ok so you have table cells with locations, like "London", "Boston" etc. Then you tap on them and it shows you a detailViewController with the details of city I get from the server. Before showing the details I check whether the city exists. If it doesn't I send an alert notification saying that the city is not found. I press OK and I want to see the table cells again. But currently when I press OK I see the empty detailViewController with the non existing city, I have to go back to masterView.It does remove the city from tableView, but the problem is going back.

Comment: In this case, you wouldn't want to segue at all, would you?

Comment: Does the check for "does the city exist" require checking the server?

Comment: Yeah I check the validity of the city from the server, so I can't possibly do it in the MasterView. I mean I can but then its double work and just painful

Comment: Call `self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)` after calling the `MasterViewController?.removeLocation(city)`.  Pass `true` if you want it to be animated, and `false` if not.